# Google Plus Domains Api insert Activities in error

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-contacts-api, google-domain-api

I try to create activity through the form 'Google+ Domains API v1' with 'plusDomains.activities.insert'

I use scopes :

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write

Request is : `https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities?preview=true&fields=access&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

parameters :

```
{
  "object": {
    "originalContent": "Test"
  },
  "access": {
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "domain"
      }
    ],
    "domainRestricted": true
  }
}
```

but I have the following error :

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
```

and I have this message : 
`You do not have permission to execute this method.`

Answer (score 0):

This API call requires OAUTH2.0 authorization not an API key. That's the reason you're getting the error.

It's clearly stated in [Activities.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert):

> "Requires authorization"

To prove this, give the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert#try-it) a go. It uses OAuth2. Your request should work.

Comment: Hi, as you can see [HERE](https://ibb.co/nHYa76) I use OAuth2. But I try you're link and I have the same error. An other idea ?